# How to reduce height of popup when keyboard appear?

Tags: ios, popup, swift3, xcode8

I am showing a popup in my view controller and the popup contains a tableview and a textfield so when I am clicking on textfield , my popup height remains same . so I want to reduce the height of my popup view when clicked on textfield. can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: You can set the frame for the popUp view on the textfieldbegin method of UITextField

Comment: you should move your popup upward when keyboard appear. when keyboard get dismiss then reset the popup to actual position.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add two this line in viewDidLoad()**

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWasShown), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeHidden), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

 // keyboard delegates method implement
 func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        print("Keyboard is active.")
        // write your code that changes pop up frame.
 }
 func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        print("Keyboard is hidden")
       // write your code that changes pop up default frame.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Dear..It is working properly ,In my case the only thing that i have to change is the notification name to  keyboardwillShown .

Comment: @Akashvishwakarma that miner changes we have to done in code i just give you hind and if its help you then approve my answer and give vote thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You try this code add notification add notification**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ClassName.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil) 
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ClassName.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

**Table automatic manage when keyboard appear**

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
var contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets
                if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)) {
                    contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!), 0.0);
                } else {
                    contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.width - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.width)!), 0.0);
                }
 self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
 self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset
            }
        }
    }
  func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
   self.tableView.contentInset = contentInset
        }
    }
```